# Google Sheets Countdown Timer for Aircraft Flight Plan "Time Remaining"

Tags: time, google-sheets

I'm struggling with a formula in Google Sheets that will display a countdown for how much time remains until an aircraft is overdue, based on a filed flight plan.

**What I have:** 2 key pieces of information about a flight plan:

- how much estimated time it will take to make the flight (ETE:
  Estimated Time Enroute)
- what time the aircraft departed (ATA: Actual Time of Departure)

**Constraints:** (mandated by company policy)

- The ETE must be entered in decimal format, in numbers of hours.  A 1hr 30min flight must have an ETE of 1.5, or a 20 minute flight must have an ETE of .3 (rounded to the nearest 10th).
- The ATA must be entered in 4-digit 24hr time, but without the colon.  1:30pm must be entered as "1330"
- The countdown timer must be displayed in minutes, rounded to the nearest whole number.  1hr 28min must be listed "88"
- The countdown should be "live" (this is solved by spreadsheet settings to update "on update or every minute".
- The countdown should easily indicate aircraft that have become "overdue" (this will be solved with conditional formatting to highlight negative numbers)

My pseudo formula is essentially just: **Now() - (ETE+ATD)**, but I'm stuck on how to get around the constraints, specifically the three different time formats (decimal hours ETE, 4-digit 24hr time ATA, and remaining time in minutes).

I've set up a dummy sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165mXKRquI4aBEEap8PIHVrFpAraaapykGqjkDg22qeU/edit?usp=sharing

---

*I've looked through [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304302/countdown-clock-for-google-sheets), but it's a GAS solution. I'd much prefer to just have a formula.  Preferably an array formula, so that it copies down to however many rows there might end up being.

**Possibly a secondary concern down the road: at the moment, we do not conduct overnight flights, but it's possible in the future.  Starting a 3hr flight at 10pm will result in the arrival time being the next day. Hopefully, there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest some testing before use, but should be worth trying:

```
=if(now()>today()+1*(left(A2,2)&":"&right(A2,2)),round(24*60*(today()+1*(left(A2,2)&":"&right(A2,2))-now())+B2*60,0),"")
```

where the ATA value is in A2 and the ETE in B2.

Could be simplified but longer might be easier to adapt for overnight, if required.

Comment: This worked great, once I formatted the ATD column to be a custom number format of 0000, so that the leading zero wasn't dropping off on a time of, for example, 0800.  I also modified the cell references to A:A2 (instead of just A2) so that the array formula would work.  Perfect!  I haven't attempted an overnight flight, though.